# Google Application Engine For Sending Emails

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a newsletter with 13k subscribers.  I would like to use Google to send the newsletter instead of the free edition of mailenable I am using currently.

The main thing that has put me off is the 2,000/day sending limit as it would take a week to send out a bi weekly newsletter which may have time sensitive information in it.

I saw a post here that said you can send over the 2,000/day limit if you use the GAE.

I went to the GAE page and had a look at the limits and it does say that you can make 1,700,000 email queries.  However, I called the Google apps sales team and they said Google says anything above 2,000 emails is spam and has no legitimate purpose (I had the feeling though that the person I was talking to was poorly trained and had no idea what the GAE was).

So would I need to create my own google app that acts like a SMTP server and uses the GAE to send the email?  Would this be the same as sending through Google Apps, i.e. DKIM header added and trusted IP?

Any help anyone can give me is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience GAE is a very **bad** platform to send bulk emails.
For a long time it didn't support DKIM or Sender Id, its hard to mange bounces, and on top of everything you need to write your own framework for bulk sending using tasks or backends. 
The cost of instances time for sending those emails might even double your cost (in $$$) for sending the newsletter.

We choose to go with Mailchimp which is IMHO the best tool for sending bulk newsletters.

Comment: I agree, I think if you're just going to use App Engine to send emails, there are better, more tailored products out there just for sending emails. Mailchimp and Mailgun are both good choices.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  I understand your advice, I had wrongly assumed it would just be like sending through google apps smtp server.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question "how can I do this?", though.

Comment: @NickJohnson Your right, but one of SO mission statement is not to waste people time, since I wastes a **lot** of time trying to use GAE to bulk email sending without great success. I believe that a warning should be in place other than just saying "just enable it in the billing"

Comment: That's a subjective judgement about utility, not an objective answer to the question. If you want to talk _about_ the question or its adviability, leave a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: @NickJohnson As a team member of GAE, would you recommend using GAE for a task like this? Would you say that you don't see any problems with it?

Comment: @NickJohnson and also what trigger my answer is his use case, not the fact that he doesn't know how to raise the daily limit on email sending. If the question was pure "How do I send more 2000 emails a day" I would send him to the billing page, but this is not the case.

Comment: No, I wouldn't suggest writing an app just to send email - the email API is built for sending email from within an app, and there are much simpler solutions if all you need to do is bulk email. But an answer should at least attempt to address the original question, and if it doesn't, it should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Billed applications can indeed send more than the default daily free limit of emails with App Engine. Once you have enabled billing, you can choose how much quota you want to dedicate to your app, including email sending.